# New "currentURL is not defined" Error in Google Apps Script Web Apps

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

A few days ago this started appearing in my Google Apps Script Web App Consoles:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: currentURL is not defined at then.catch.e (content_script_bundle.js:13)

What might this be?

Comment: It is just a bunch of minified script.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`content_script_bundle.js` is likely a script within a Chrome Extension. *Ghostery* has such a js file. Basically, it has caught an error of some kind

```
window.console.error("Could not run content script", e, currentURL())
```

Unfortunately, the line in the script that pushes the error to the console itself has a minor bug whereby `currentURL` has not been defined so it squawks.

Just turn off Ghostery or whatever and the error will disappear. Although, you can just ignore it. Easiest though is to right-click the console message and select "Hide messages from content_script_bundle.js" if it's bothering you. If it is *Ghostery then mark your site as trusted* as noted in the comment below. Probably the best solution.

This is a screenshot from Chrome Inspector.

[image]

Comment: You can mark your site as trusted in Ghostery and the error disappears